# jQuery autocomplete populate array on input text

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Here's the code that populate the same array given by file source;

```
$("#input-search").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "SearchList.igx",
            data: { name: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
            //dataType: "json", 
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#input-search').val(ui.item.value);
        },
        cache: false,

    });
```

and here's the SearchList.igx populated;

```
[{label:"John Doe", value:"0123"},{label:"Joshua Poe", value:"0124"}]
```

It's view like this:

[image: dynamic search autocomplete]

How can I view it as a populated suggested text like some autocomplete output view?

Comment: Is `data` coming back as a string or parsed JSON? PS, `[{label:"John Doe", value:"0123"},{label:"Joshua Poe", value:"0124"}]` isn't JSON.

Comment: yes it is, but if I uncommentout the dataType: "json" no response.

Comment: `[{label:"John Doe", value:"0123"},{label:"Joshua Poe", value:"0124"}]` isn't JSON, it is JavaScript, they're different. Try sending back real JSON with a correct Content-type header.

Comment: but in the tutorial autocomplete json returns this data format [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

Comment: That's the *parsed* version, JSON would look like `[{"label":"Choice1","value":"0124"},...`. Try adding a `console.log(data)` and see if you get an array or a string.

Comment: I got it!! :) the label and value MUST have a double quote! hahaha! thanks @mu is too short